# Compiling a class with separate source and header

Tags: c++, codeblocks

It won't compile, I have the following errors:

- foo.h no such file in directory;
- foo has not been declared;
- num was not declared in this scope
- foo is not a class or a namespace

It is odd, to say the least, because I just used the code blocks "Create a new Class" and then added it to this project. This is the source code:

Header:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
class foo
{
    private:
    int num;
    public:
        foo();
    void set_num(int set);
    int get_num();
};
#endif // FOO_H
```

the cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

foo::foo()
{
    num = 10;
}

void foo :: set_num(int set)
{
    num = set;
}

int foo :: get_num()
{
    return num;
}
```

Disregard the calss itself and what it does, the problem is that it doesn't compile even though I used the default code blocks class creation setting.

The errors:

```
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|1|error: foo.h: No such file or directory|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|3|error: 'foo' has not been declared|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|3|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'foo' with no type|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp||In function 'int foo()':|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|5|error: 'num' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|6|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|8|error: 'foo' is not a class or namespace|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp||In function 'void set_num(int)':|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|10|error: 'num' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|13|error: 'foo' is not a class or namespace|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp||In function 'int get_num()':|
C:\Users\SameTime\Desktop\CodeBLocks\ASDD\src\foo.cpp|15|error: 'num' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 8 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Is the header file called `foo.h` and in the same directory?

Comment: Yes it is. The IDE handles that part.

Comment: Please post what errors you get.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "foo.h no such file in directory"

Comment: Which IDE are you using? How does it call the compiler? Of foo.h is in the same diretory it should always work.

Comment: If you manually look in your `src` directory, do you see `foo.h`?

Comment: Are you compiling on a system that has case sensitive files?  Perhaps it is Foo.h or FOO.h?

Comment: The IDE which I am using is CodeBlocks; Yes I see foo.h and foo.cpp in the source directory.

Comment: And it's certainly the same name (case, no spaces, etc)

Comment: Yes, it most certanly is + I tried all possible combinations of upper and lower case letters just in case.

Comment: Are these two files the only files you created when you compile?

Comment: Not really. Since this is something I have done a lot of times, I was shocked and tried to make a few dummy classes to see if I am just tired and doing something terribly wrong, so there are a few classes in the project folder.

Comment: Have you tried #include "./foo.h" ?

Comment: I tried it,  didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the header is not in the same directory you must either specify the path in the include command, or you must add -I Path directive to your makefile or include settings.

Maybe this link also helps as codeblock seems to have problems.

[http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingchyne/2011/03/codeblocks-failed-to-find-the-header-file/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140601222853/http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingchyne/2011/03/codeblocks-failed-to-find-the-header-file/)

Comment: That's just it, it is in the same directory.

Comment: This is the solution, thank you for the link, I will add it to the main thread.

Comment: Still find it strange though. :) It could be that codeblock calls the compiler not from the directory where the source is, that is the only explanation I can currently think of.

Comment: Using absolute paths means that you cannot copy the project to a different folder, let alone computer. That may not be necessary now but is indispensable in the long run (think of projects in git which you clone to new locations and friends' computers, for example). I'd suggest to find out "from where" CodeBlocks compiles (possibly the project file, which has an `include` and a `src` directory under it, or such) and use *relative paths* for the include directives.

Answer (score 2):

Can you navigate to the source directory in the command line and try to compile manually to ensure that the error isn't with the IDE?

If your IDE is using g++ (it probably is) then the command would be `g++ foo.cpp`

Comment: I don't really work with the command line. Though I changed the IDE and the class started working... this problem is getting more and more interesting, the problem shouldn't be in the IDE, since CodeBlocks is widely used.

Comment: This is part of the reason why I am not a huge fan of using IDEs for a language like C++, I feel that they add unnecessary complexity. I would suggest learning a little about the command line (it doesn't take much to be able to navigate to a directory and compile) and makefiles (which will allow you to use a very short command to compile even a large project).

Comment: @drew.cuthbert Good IDEs are indispensable in my opinion; no so much for compiling (best would be to use cmake these days, and that works trivially from the command line when the cmake files are there) but for source code navigation, side-by-side file viewing, and especially debugging. Yes, all of that can be done if you know your emacs or vim but that's not everybody's cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Navigate to the folder containing the files
3. Make sure the header is called "foo.h" (You know Explorer sometimes hides file extensions, right?)

If that doesn't do it, your compiler is broken.